# C++ (SPOJ - POL-polowa) - problem with compilation

Tags: c++

I have problem with making correct code for this task in SPOJ https://pl.spoj.com/problems/POL/.
When I wrote all what I needed, program worked correctly. But when I tried to convert it in function, I have on ideone.com problem like this -> double free or corruption (out). Can anybody help me please ? What I am doing wrong ? I am beginner and I realize that can be very trivial.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int polowa()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    string slowa[100]={};
    string nowe_slowa[100]={};
    for (int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
       cin>>slowa[i];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        int k=slowa[i].length()/2;
        nowe_slowa[i]=slowa[i].substr(0,k);
        cout<<nowe_slowa[i]<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
polowa();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int polowa()` promises to return an `int`, but the `return` keyword is conspicuously absent from the function.

Comment: [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know where you are storing the data if `t` is greater than 100.

Comment: Where is `#include <string>`?

Comment: When I wanted to make array of strings with non size, that was impossible. So i written size 100. When it comes to function polowa(), should I change it to string ?

Comment: Yes I know but when I included <string> there is still problem when compilating.

Comment: You might want to look up [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Looking over the code, you never use more than one element at a time. Odds are good you could rewrite this function to use no arrays and only one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `int polowa()` promises to return an `int`, but the `return` keyword is conspicuously absent from the function.
>
> Looking over the code, you never use more than one element at a time. Odds are good you could rewrite this function to use no arrays and only one loop.  – [user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301)

You don't have to separate reading input and print output. Arrays are not needed. Proposed implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    unsigned tests;
    std::cin >> tests;
    while (tests--)
    {
        std::string word;
        std::cin >> word;
        std::cout << word.substr(0, word.length() / 2) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is ok. But i when i want to make this as a function it doesnt work.

Comment: Create a new question with your new code, or say something more.

Answer (score 0):

According to Dessus proposition I wanted to make this code as a function called in int main(). But SPOJ can't accept me this code (when i am compiling this in code blocks, everythings okay).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string nowe_slowo(int t)
{
    while (t--)
    {
        std::string word;
        std::cin >> word;
        std::cout<<word.substr(0, word.length() / 2)<<"\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
unsigned tests;
std::cin >> tests;
nowe_slowo(tests);
}
```

Comment: You don't return a string in a function, so replace the return type with void. Rename the function more suited to the context, or isolate it differently. Enable compiler warnings to avoid simple problems.